# How to control which http request to execute first in php backend?

Tags: php, laravel, http, http-post

I have received both main response request and backend response request from payment side.

It will run my function to update my transaction table to record payment details. There's will be a unique payment id pass into my function.

for example,

```
 public function response(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->id_trans;
    $trans = new Transaction;
    $trans->id_trans = $id;
    $trans->....
    $trans->save();
}

public function backend_response(Request $request) {
   $id = $request->id_trans;
   $check_trans = DB::table('transaction')->where('id_trans', $id)->first();
   if($check_trans)
       echo "OK";
       exit;
   else
       // insert here..
}
```

I found that it by pass my checking condition in `backend_response()` due to it execute before transaction insert into my table. How can i prevent this issue update my table twice? How can i ensure `response()` to execute first before `backend_response()`?

Comment: Can you provide more details like how you invoke those 2 functions / Route Definitions ?

Comment: For example, i have this 2 route, www.abc.com/response and www.abc.com/backend_response. I integrate with other side. They will post status back to this 2 route. I need to select which function to do my update, in case response() failed, then backup_response will only trigger for 3 times until received OK acknowledgement. But at first, both response and backup_response will be called. I have no idea how to let response() to execute first to insert payment record.